# Parsing a string input into a lambda function (Python)

Tags: python, input, lambda, type-conversion

How can I parse a string input into the proper form for it to be executed as mapping regulation in a lambda function?

```
 fx=type(input("Enter a polynomial: "))
```

This is my input, I want to enter arbirtray polynomials.

```
f= lambda x: fx
```

Now i want my lambda function to be able to execute the strings from the input function just as if they were normal mapping regulations like `x**2` for instance.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you mean you want to input a string that represents a polynomial and store it in variable `fx`, then parse it into a new string format that can be evaluated more easily? Or do you want a function that evaluates that string and can be used in another, lambda function? Or something else? I hope you realize that your lambda expression as written is meaningless.

Comment: `fx` will always be `str`, unless you're using Python 2.x.

Comment: Yes, i would like to do the second option. The expression is part of a bigger program, this is only the part that causes me my problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First things first, `input()` behaves differently in Python 2 and Python 3, as  specified in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x) answer.

[`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) is one of the simplest options:

## Python 3

```
>>> fx = input("Enter a polynomial: ")
Enter a polynomial: x**2 + 2*x + 1
>>> f = lambda x: eval(fx)
>>> f(1)
4
```

## Python 2

```
>>> fx = raw_input("Enter a polynomial: ")
Enter a polynomial: x**2 + 2*x + 1
>>> f = lambda x: eval(fx)
>>> f(1)
4
```

Be careful though, as `eval()` can execute arbitrary code.